# How to access the Internet through Proxy in C#

Tags: .net, proxy

I'm designing a Windows Form application using C#.  The application performs its functions smoothly when connected to the Internet but the real problem starts when we try the application in our College.

Our College connects to the Net using proxy gateways. The Proxy server is `192.168.120.5` and Proxy Port `8080`.  Every Student is given an unique user name and password.

How can I get ahead through this obstacle?  I'm trying to create a proxy connection to the target IP:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");  
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("192.168.120.5", 8080);
```

Will that help me in any way?  If yes, where do I enter the Username and Password Credentials?

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use that... though it may be simpler use the WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);
proxyObject.Credientials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, "bla");
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
req.Proxy = proxyObject;
```

though as a side note you may be able to use the local default credentials by setting

```
proxyObject.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

If you do try to use that you have to make sure that proxyObject.Credintials = null. 
The msdn site on all of this is here [MSDN WebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy_members.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna a little bit late but this may help other persons in the same situation, first create a new class for your proxy configuration as below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace Your_name_space
{
    public class Proxy : IWebProxy
    {
        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get
            {
                return new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domaine");
            }
            set { }
        }

        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {
            return new Uri("your_proxy_address:port");
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Next add this as a module in your app config under configuration/system.net section.

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false" >
      <module type="Your_name_space.Proxy , your_assembly_name" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

if you do want to use default session credentials, in the proxy class, replace 
this :

```
new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domaine");
```

by

```
CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

I hope this helps.