# connect to website using a free proxy server programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, proxy

I need to connect to a website using a proxy server. I can do this manually, for example I can use the online proxy `http://zend2.com` and then surf to `www.google.com`. But this must be done programmatically. I know I can use `WebProxy` class but how can I write a code so a proxy server can be used?

Anyone can give me a code snippet as example or something?

thanks

Comment: You know you can use `WebProxy`. That's the solution. What did you tried ? What do you mean by "connect a website" ? using the browser ? Using a c# webrequest ?

Comment: Yes in the title you can read that I want to do this programmatically (so using C#)

Comment: programmatically what ? Both hypothesis I wrote can be done programmatically

Comment: how can you make a connection with a website using a browser programmatically?

Comment: I may have not been clear, but I want you to describe what you mean by "connection".

Comment: Getting a response packet from the server? Client server, GET and RESPONSE, you know?

Comment: read my updated answer for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding of zend2 works, you can populate an url like this :

> http://zend2.com/bro.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&b=12&f=norefer

for browsing google.

I C#, build the url like this :

```
string targetUrl = "http://www.google.com";
string proxyUrlFormat = "http://zend2.com/bro.php?u={0}&b=12&f=norefer";
string actualUrl = string.Format(proxyUrlFormat, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(targetUrl));

// Do something with the proxy-ed url
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(actualUrl));
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

string content = null;
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Steve B. But the first link you gave only fills the textbox in zend2 but doesn't actually go to `google.com`

Comment: I suspect the site produces a cookie. The url works on my browser, but not with another browser. You'll have to simulate an http post on the page, then keep track of the cookies in order to make it works

Comment: Actually, the use of zend2 is not obliged.  I can also use a public proxy server that I just found http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-225490. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I confirm, there are some cookies generated by the site. So instead of using a Get request like I did, you'll have to create a POST request on the zend2.com home page, then analyse the results where the redirected url should appear

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebProxy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx)

MSDN code

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
req.Proxy = proxyObject;
```

In your case

```
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://zend2.com",true);
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("www.google.com");
req.Proxy = proxyObject;
```

Comment: @user1410501 yes. please read the documentation for complete understanding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.aspx

Comment: I don't think it will work because zend2.com is just a website that offers you to go to a website using proxy manually?

Comment: @user1410501 please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175104/how-to-access-the-internet-through-proxy-in-c-sharp

Comment: When you create a new WebProxy class , you can use ProxySharp to get a server ip and port for you to use when making the web request.  https://github.com/m-henderson/ProxySharp